# How to know current timezone of Ireland in a given time in java

Tags: java, time

In the summer Ireland use `IST, UTC+01:00` and `Greenwich Mean Time` in the winter. I get datetime without any GMT information from a source, and it's from Ireland. I need to convert it into GMT+0. But the challenge is Ireland timezone is different in different seasons.

Comment: That is impossible. Some timestamps correspond to two different moments in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can’t (always)

Just to spell out what I think talex meant in the comment. On the last Sunday in October Ireland switches from summer time to standard time. The clocks in Ireland are turned back from 2 AM to 1 AM. So an hour after it was 1 AM it is again 1 AM. The times repeat. This is known as an *overlap*. (The opposite, when clocks are turned forward, is called a *gap*.) The implication? If for example the time you get is given as 1:30 in that night, you don’t know whether it’s from the first time it was 1:30 — 1:30 IST — or the second time it was 1:30 — 1:30 GMT. Or in code:

```
    String dateTimeStr = "2021-10-31T01:30:00";
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr);
    
    System.out.println(ldt.atZone(IRELAND).withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap());
    System.out.println(ldt.atZone(IRELAND).withLaterOffsetAtOverlap());
```

I used this constant:

```
private static final ZoneId IRELAND = ZoneId.of("Europe/Dublin");
```

And the output is:

> ```
> 2021-10-31T01:30+01:00[Europe/Dublin]
> 2021-10-31T01:30Z[Europe/Dublin]
> ```

For timestamps not originating from those two hours in that night you will not have any problem.

To check whether you have an ambiguous timestamp compare the two `ZonedDateTime` objects that I printed in the above code. For the vast majority of cases they will be equal. Take for example:

```
    String dateTimeStr = "2021-10-07T18:48:00";
```

> ```
> 2021-10-07T18:48+01:00[Europe/Dublin]
> 2021-10-07T18:48+01:00[Europe/Dublin]
> ```

Comment: Wow! What a co-incidence! Yet another useful answer, posted almost at the same time when I posted my answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you using `ZonedDateTime` ([reference documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)) and as ZoneId you should use `Europe/Dublin`. It should observe the timezone changes according to seasons.

Answer (score 1):

If You are sure the time is from Ireland You can hardcode ZoneId like: `ZoneId.of("Europe/Dublin")`

And then parse the time for Ireland like this:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-07-01T08:00");
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Dublin");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, zoneId);
```

More on ZonedDateTime here:
https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/add-a-timezone-to-localdatetime-with-zoneddatetime-in-java-8

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime
.of( 
    LocalDate.parse( "2022-06-23" ) , 
    LocalTime.parse( "15:30" ) , 
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Dublin" )  
)
.toInstant()
.atOffset(
    ZoneOffset.UTC
)
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Uen6j2). We see that in the summer next year, the people of Ireland will have their clocks set to one hour ahead of UTC: 15:30 in Dublin time will be 14:30 in UTC time.

> 2022-06-23T14:30Z

## Details

Your title asks:

> How to know current timezone of Ireland in a given time in java

Ireland  has only one time zone, per my reading of [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_Republic_of_Ireland): `Europe/Dublin`.

You are confusing offsets with zones.

An offset-from-UTC is simply a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead of, or behind, the modern temporal meridian.

A time zone is much more. A time zone is a named **history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset** used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians.

A real time zone is named in `Continent/Region` format. The 2-4 character pseudo-zones such as `IST` are not time zones, and should be avoided as they are not standardized and are not even unique! To some, `IST` is *Ireland Standard Time*, while to others `IST` is *India Standard Time*.

You said:

> I get datetime without any GMT information from a source, and it's from Ireland.

So take your date and time-of-day and add the time zone you presume was intended. You get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

```
LocalDate ld = … ;
LocalTime lt = … ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Dublin" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

Adjust to UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds) by extracting a [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

For more flexibility such as generating text in various formats, convert to [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are good. However, they have missed an important piece of information that the OP needs, and that information is:

**The [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) has been designed to adjust the timezone offset automatically.**

It means that depending on whether the Date-Time is a summer/winter time, you will find it reflecting different timezone offsets (of course, if [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is applicable).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Dublin");
        ZonedDateTime zdtSummerIST = LocalDate.of(2021, 6, 15).atStartOfDay(zoneId);
        ZonedDateTime zdtWinterIST = LocalDate.of(2021, 11, 15).atStartOfDay(zoneId);
        System.out.println(zdtSummerIST);
        System.out.println(zdtWinterIST);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-15T00:00+01:00[Europe/Dublin]
2021-11-15T00:00Z[Europe/Dublin]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/g6yHQG)

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

#### How do I convert a Date-Time string without timezone to `ZonedDateTime`?

Parse the Date-Time string without timezone into `LocalDateTime` which can be converted into a `ZonedDateTime` using [`LocalDateTime#atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Dublin");
        String input = "07/10/2021 18:50:15";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(input, dtf);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(zoneId);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-10-07T18:50:15+01:00[Europe/Dublin]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/xoBkdN)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>